# Ecto - format of returned value during error on update_all

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

When using Ecto's `update_all` to update all matching records, what is the format of the returned values in an error situation? The documentation is a little vague about what to expect back - 'It returns a tuple containing the number of entries and any returned result as second element.'

For example, let's say there are 10 matching records and for whatever reason, the `update` action fails on 2 of those records.  My assumption is that the returned value would look like this:

```
{8, [{:error, error info}, {:error, error info}]}
```

Is that correct? Would the errors come back as a list of tuples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if the UPDATE query fails, `Repo.update_all` throws an error. No changes are actually saved in the database if this happens.

The list in the second element of the returned tuple is the data you've asked the query to return using the `RETURNING` clause, e.g. `query |> Repo.update_all([], returning: [:id])` will return the updated structs with just the `id` field populated and `returning: true` will return structs with all the fields populated.

Here's an example of an error occurring in one record of an update query:

```
iex(1)> from(p in Post, select: p.id) |> Repo.all
[debug] QUERY OK source="posts" db=1.1ms queue=0.1ms
SELECT p0."id" FROM "posts" AS p0 []
[1, 2, 3]

iex(2)> from(p in Post, where: p.id in [2, 3], update: [set: [id: fragment("CASE WHEN ? = 3 THEN 1 ELSE ? END", p.id, p.id)]]) |> Repo.update_all([])
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 23505 (unique_violation): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "posts_pkey"

    table: posts
    constraint: posts_pkey

Key (id)=(1) already exists.
[debug] QUERY ERROR source="posts" db=4.8ms
UPDATE "posts" AS p0 SET "id" = CASE WHEN p0."id" = 3 THEN 1 ELSE p0."id" END WHERE (p0."id" IN (2,3)) []
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:436: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.execute_and_cache/7
```

Comment: Dogbert, you have been incredibly helpful. Thanks!